# Problem to localize images for iPhone in xcode 3.2.3

Tags: xcode, localization, uiimage

Friday afternoon and all but hope that different timezones will help me with this...

I have four files that I have localized in my project.

Localizable.strings

InfoPlist.strings

AppData.plist

AppImage.png

For these files I have a .lproj folder for spa (Spanish) and por (Portuguese).

It works fine with the strings in the app, app name in InfoPlist.strings and the data from the AppData.plist. But the AppImage.png refuse to change to any language!

I used the same method for all files (info-localize-add localization and then copied files in finder). I have tried a clean build, reset the simulator and also on a 3G iPhone all with the same result: image does not change...

I load the image with [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppImage.png"]

Any clues where I can start my troubleshooting?

Thanks

Comment: Just tried with another project and the same problem. Did the same thing, Info - Localize - Add Localization (in this case swe for Swedish) and then revealed the file in finder and replaced the image with a Swedish version. Still it refuses to show the Swe version even if I can see it in xcodes. A localized xib file is working just fine, so it's not a NSLocale issue.


Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: An update. In my second project I localized a xib file that use two images in a button. In IB I see the localized image, but not when testing in the simulator. I'm going crazy here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never got it to work, so used this solution instead:

http://www.pushplay.net/blog_detail.php?id=33

Answer (score 1):

I was getting close to giving up, but I found that you have to also delete the following folder:

> ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I'll try that next time I have an issue.

Comment: This still appears to be a problem, even in XCode 4.5. I noticed that a lot of people are talking about deleting the whole app from either the device or the simulator and then rebuilding and deploying from scratch. While this does appear to fix the problem, I found that it continues to happen for existing users after they update to your new, localized version on the App Store. Unless those users will also delete the app and re-download, you may need to go with Structurer's solution above.